# Xamarin Map and returning user to the app and location error

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

Ok, I am using Xamrian Essentials from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/maps?tabs=android to use a map in my android application in xamrian forms.

However, How does one make sure that the app returns the user to the previous page of my app.

```
private async void BtnDirections_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
        var address = lbldeliveryAddreess.Text;
        var locations = await Geocoding.GetLocationsAsync(address);

        if (locations != null)
        {
            lbllat.Text = locations.First().Latitude.ToString();
            lbllong.Text = locations.First().Longitude.ToString();
        }

        var location = new Location(Convert.ToDouble(lbllat.Text), Convert.ToDouble(lbllong.Text));
        var options = new MapLaunchOptions { NavigationMode = NavigationMode.Driving };

        await Map.OpenAsync(location, options);
}
```

I hope someone can help me out just want my user experience to be correct in the app.

When I launch the map it does not display the location in the to field also here it says it cant navigate to their.

The address is in the uk

[image]

Comment: If using simulator in map, first you need to set current location manually.So your destination adress can be right to find a route there.

Answer (score 0):

> When I launch the map it does not display the location in the to field also here it says it cant navigate to their.The address is in the uk

You need to manually change location of simulator to be your want test location,so a route of navigation can show properly.

1. Open simulator, click here .

[image]

2. Latitude and longitude can be modified here.
   [image]